# SwiftUI & WidgetKit: Why Intent Handler does not load saved data?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm building a Widget with dynamic configuration. I provide a dynamic list of options with an Intents Extension - inside Intent Handler (code below).

However only `sampleData` shows up, but not the `userScrums` when tapping on **"Edit Widget"**. 
Why it doesn't load `userScrums`?

```
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension {
    
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,
        // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.
        
        return self
    }
    
}

extension IntentHandler: ScrumSelectionIntentHandling {    
    func provideScrumOptionsCollection(for intent: ScrumSelectionIntent) async throws -> INObjectCollection<ScrumType> {
        let sampleScrums = DailyScrum.sampleData.map { scrum in
            ScrumType(identifier: scrum.title, display: scrum.title)
        }
        let userScrums = try? await ScrumStore.load().map { scrum in
            ScrumType(identifier: scrum.title, display: scrum.title)
        }
        let allScrums = sampleScrums + (userScrums ?? [])
        let collection = INObjectCollection(items: allScrums)
        return collection
    }

//    func provideScrumOptionsCollection(for intent: ScrumSelectionIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<ScrumType>?, Error?) -> Void) {}
    
}
```

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class ScrumStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var scrums: [DailyScrum] = []
    
    private static func fileURL() throws -> URL {
        try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                       in: .userDomainMask,
                                       appropriateFor: nil,
                                       create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("scrums.data")
    }
    
    static func load() async throws -> [DailyScrum] {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            load { result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                case .success(let scrums):
                    continuation.resume(returning: scrums)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    static func load(completion: @escaping (Result<[DailyScrum], Error>)->Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            do {
                let fileURL = try fileURL()
                guard let file = try? FileHandle(forReadingFrom: fileURL) else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(.success([]))
                    }
                    return
                }
                let dailyScrums = try JSONDecoder().decode([DailyScrum].self, from: file.availableData)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(dailyScrums))
                }
            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @discardableResult
    static func save(scrums: [DailyScrum]) async throws -> Int {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            save(scrums: scrums) { result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                case .success(let scrumsSaved):
                    continuation.resume(returning: scrumsSaved)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    static func save(scrums: [DailyScrum], completion: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>)->Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            do {
                let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(scrums)
                let outfile = try fileURL()
                try data.write(to: outfile)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(scrums.count))
                }
            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You likely need AppGroups, if the files isn't stored in a shared location the Extension won't see what the main app is seeing and vice versa